# How to incorporate human control in DQN

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I'm planning on training a Mario agent to play by itself using DQN. But I also want to be able to control the agent if it gets stuck on a pipe, for example, then allow it to carry on playing by itself. How would I extract the specific state where it needs help?

Comment: Just check whether there's no change in state for some number of steps? Or if the situation repeats over some number of steps.

Comment: You might be interested in the DAgger algorithm ([paper](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~sross1/publications/Ross-AIStats11-NoRegret.pdf)) where it alternates between supervised learning on existing expert data and adding new ones (human expert/oracle) by querying on the states visited by the latest policy. AFAIK, the algorithm does not specifically filter for states that it currently have trouble with, but simply focuses on getting new expert input on its current distribution of states. This [chapter](http://ciml.info/dl/v0_99/ciml-v0_99-ch18.pdf) has a more accessible description of the algorithm.